# using 24hr timestamp in sqoop import

Tags: timestamp, sqoop

I am trying to import data from oracle using a free form query and need to store timestamp in 24 hr format.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:(server credntials) \
 --username ***** --password ***** \
 --query "select emp_uid, emp_name, salary, to_char(create_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_char(last_sal_update_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), coalesce(to_char(last_sal_update_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_char(create_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as hadoop_import_timestamp from emp.emp_sal where last_sal_update_timestamp < (to_char('2013-01-21 09:16:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) and \$CONDITIONS" \
 --split-by "to_char(hadoop_import_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')" \
 --target-dir /user/sal/emp_sal \
--map-column-hive CREATE_TIMESTAMP=TIMESTAMP,LAST_SAL_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=TIMESTAMP,HADOOP_IMPORT_TIMESTAMP=TIMESTAMP \
--hive-import \
--hive-table empdet.empsal \
--hive-drop-import-delims
```

But I get an invalid number error on trying to run it

Comment: please share error logs and hive table structure

Comment: And a DESCRIBE of the Oracle Table plz

Answer (score 0):

It works when the split-by is with the primary key(emp_uid)